# Fill entire row of 2D-Array in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, 2d, row, fill

I have a 2-dimensional array that I want to fill with values, but only on specific rows and columns (not all of them). For example, I want all the values for an angle of 15° in column 15, for 30° in column 30 and so on. Same with the rows.

I could fill in every value manually with both indices, but that's kind of against the point of an array, right?

Is there a way to fill an entire Row of an array by defining the index for the row and then having the second index with the value together?

Something like this:

```
Dim values(300,45) As Double

'I want to fill row 15 in columns 15, 30 and 45
values(15) = {{15, 0.06},{30, 0.04},{45, 0.03}}

'now row 20, again just columns 15, 30 and 45
values(20) = {{15, 0.26},{30, 0.23},{45, 0.17}}
```

I know it doesn't work that way, just to give you an idea what I imagined.

I hope my problem is understandable and thank you for your help :)

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a **column** - not a "coloumn" :..

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing I know of in the VB language that provides that type of utility.  You could use an extension method to get close to that syntax though.

```
Module ArrayExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub LoadValues(Of T)(arrayToFill As T(,), rowIndex As Int32, ParamArray items() As Array)
        For Each ar As Array In items
            Dim colIndex As Int32 = CInt(ar.GetValue(0))
            Dim val As T = CType(ar.GetValue(1), T)
            arrayToFill(rowIndex, colIndex) = val
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then using your example:

```
Dim values(300, 45) As Double

'I want to fill row 15 in coloumns 15, 30 and 45
values.LoadValues(15, {15, 0.06}, {30, 0.04}, {45, 0.03})

'now row 20, again just coloums 15, 30 and 45
values.LoadValues(20, {15, 0.26}, {30, 0.23}, {45, 0.17})
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)
Thanks a lot!